# Why is nginx redirecting to another site when setting up SSL on my new site?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I have a droplet on DigitalOcean, running `Ubuntu 16.04`, which I started sharing with a friend of mine. He already has a webpage running on the droplet with `nginx` and today I started setting my Wordpress site on it too.

I successfully got my site running with my own domain with a dummy `info.php` file on it to test if it works. I set up my site separately in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`.

Now I want to set SSL encryption for my site using `certbot`. I installed `certbot` and the plugin for `nginx` successfully. The problem I'm facing now is that when I try to go to my site, `https://example.com/info.php` or `http://example.com/info.php` I get an `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error. So I went to the config file for my site which looked like this:

```
server {
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
        location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location / {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
        if ($host = www.example.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        if ($host = example.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

And commented the entire last `server` block. Now I don't get error but instead now when I go to `https://example.com/info.php` or `http://example.com/info.php` I get redirected to the HTTPS version of my friend site, say `https://myfriendsite.com`!

This is the config file of my friend site:

```
upstream mysite_development {
    server unix:/webapps/Backend/mysite/run/gunicorn.sock
        fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.myfriendsite.com;
    return 301 https://myfriendsite.com$request_uri;
    # rewrite ^/(.*) https://myfriendsite.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myfriendsite.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /webapps/Backend/certificates/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /webapps/Backend/certificates/myfriendsite.com.key;

    access_log /webapps/Backend/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/Backend/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /webapps/Backend/mysite/static/;
    }

    location /media/price_list/ {
        internal;
        alias /webapps/Backend/mysite/media/price_list/;
    }

    location /media/electronic_bill/ {
        internal;
        types { application/octet-stream .pdf; }
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
        alias /webapps/Backend/mysite/media/electronic_bill/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /webapps/Backend/mysite/media/;
    }

    location /assets/ {
        alias /webapps/Backend/mysite/static/assets/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://mysite_development;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.myfriendsite.com;
    return 301 https://myfriendsite.com$request_uri;
}
```

If I remove SSL from my site it starts working as intended but as soon as I enable SSL for my site it gets redirected to my friend site! I can't really find what's causing the redirect.

Edit: if it is important, I'm using Cloudflare as my DNS server. My friend is using the DNS server provided by DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it wasn't an issue with `nginx`, the issue was related to Cloudflare Flexible SSL. I solved it by changing the SSL mode from `Flexible` to `Strict` in the Cloudflare Dashboard.

You can read more about this [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/653976/redirect-loop-using-cloudflares-flexible-ssl/654018#654018%20%22%22).

Comment: How to do it when cert from `Letsencrypt`?